# How do I safely convert Pandas columns to datetime (if they could be other dtype)?

Tags: python, pandas

When pandas loads data, from a csv, for example, it runs [`infer_objects()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) (or something that does the same thing). `infer_objects` tries to determine an appropriate dtype for each column loaded. It sometimes (always?) does not infer datetime columns.

In order to do dynamic down-stream analysis I need the dtypes to be assigned automatically. I want to convert object columns to datetimes dynamically.  I really like using `infer_datetime_format=True` within [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). This is great because I don't always know the format that the date will arrive in. But this won't work long-term because it's *too* effective.

It won't throw any errors on int or float columns (because those technically could be dates). Alternatively if I only try to convert columns with dtype of 'object' I *can* get it to error noisely with `errors = 'raise'`. But for many datetime columns I deal with I prefer to coerce format errors (`errors = 'coerce'`) rather than prevent the column from being converted.

So has anyone found a good way to best detect columns that are realistically dates?

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing a customized `date_parser`:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=[0,1,2,3],
            date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example date_parser function that would work (even using psudo-code would help); I see the lambda you provided but I don't think that would work. And how could I tell it to check every column using parse_dates. I won't know how many columns there will be.

Comment: I don't know anything that can auto parse dates for you. Generally, you can't tell `20201216` is a date or an integer.